# Is there a bug in the Bookdown TOC when repeating section names

Tags: bookdown

I have noticed in my own `bookdown` documents that when I repeat section names, e.g. I have a "Homework" section in each chapter, all links in the document outline will redirect to the first instance of this section name. I thought I was configuring something incorrectly and was waiting to fix it, but then I noticed that the [Geocomputation with R](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/) book exhibits the same behavior.

To reproduce this error, go to https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/, and click the "Exercises" section in any chapter. All links redirect to the Exercises in chapter 1. Have others experienced this?

I would add that this MWE does *not* demonstrate the problem, though I believe it should based on what I am seeing:

```
---
title: "A Book"
author: "Frida Gomam"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::gitbook: default
  #bookdown::pdf_book: default
---

# First chapter

## Sustainability

## Exercises

# Second chapter

## Infrastructure

## Exercises
```

Comment: This will be fixed in **bookdown** 0.21: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-bookdown-version-021